# AngularJS: delete charAt last index of ","

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to write code in `AngularJS` to delete character at last index of ",".

**Here is equivalent java code:**

```
stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.lastIndexOf(","));
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you try searching for equivalents before asking? It should not be very difficult in `lastIndexOf()`'s case.

Comment: You are trying to delete the last comma?

Comment: @epascarello, yes last occurrence of comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

```
str = str.replace(/,([^,]*)$/, "$1");
```

or

```
var pos = str.lastIndexOf(",");
str = str.substr(0, pos) + str.substr(pos + 1);
```

Comment: +1 Love the regex answer!  Explained as:  "If you find a comma with no commas after it before the end, capture everything after the comma and replace the whole thing with that)

Comment: Thanks for not teasing me because I ended a " with a ). :P

Answer (score 2):

### Not an answer, but something I found:

Funny enough, while playing around in the browser console, I noticed something (either an extension or StackOverflow's JS) had added a `String.prototype.splitOnLast` that looks like this:

```
function (d){d=this.lastIndexOf(d);return 0>d?[this]:[this.substr(0,d),this.substr(d)]}
```

which looks something like this:

```
function splitOnLast(str, sep) {
     index = str.lastIndexOf(sep);
     return 0 > index ? [str] : [str.substr(0, index), str.substr(index)];
}
```

... although that returns the last ',' as part of the second array element... so you'd need to up the index by one:

```
function splitOnLast(str, sep) {
     index = str.lastIndexOf(sep);
     return 0 > index ? [str] : [str.substr(0, index), str.substr(index + 1)];
}
```

Sort of funny... Community wiki'ed